# Make Styling Stay The Same

Tags: css, styling

Is there a way I can make my website styling (e.g: position, width, height e.t.c.) stay the same even when I have changed my browser height / width or opened Inspect Element.

Comment: Not with *just* CSS (assuming you're using entirely relative units on page-load and *then* resizing the window); though with JavaScript you could apply fixed dimensions to the `<body>` element, once the page has loaded, and then style the descendants in the same relative units.

Comment: Simple answer. Yes.  My questions is "why?" What's your purpose.  We could help

Comment: would you be able to tell me how to use fixed dimensions? thanks

Comment: simple..use media queries or  Bootstrap. By these  you can set the css for whole site in any resolution..

Comment: im new to this sooo.. i dont know what media queries or bootstrap are

Comment: Then read from here or search on google. Bootstrap http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ and media queries http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add one wrapper div and apply your minimum width and height properties.

**HTML**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- Add all your HTML -->
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 #wrapper
 {
   width:1024px; 
   height:768px; 
   min-width:1024px;
   min-height:768px;
   margin:0px auto;
   overflow:auto;
 }
```

This will fix your page width and height on any resolution and scrollbar will appear if they open in less resolution. White empty spaces will come on left and reight side if they open in bigger resolutions.

Comment: would it go    <div id="wrapper"><html></html></div> or html on the outside?

Comment: Nope. should be `<body><div id="wrapper"><!-- html content code --></div></body>